# Saving RTM files compatible to previous versions of Report Builder

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, compatibility, delphi-5, reportbuilder

I have some report templates saved as .RTM files. They are used by an application built with Delphi 5 and ReportBuilder 5.

Now, I just need to change the logo at the top of these report templates, no need to rebuild the application. I am working with Delphi 7 and ReportBuilder 11, if i try to open and edit those .RTM files, the new files will have new properties which are not recognized by the application (OutlineSettings, Email settings, Border.Color etc)

`Can I save the template to a format compatible to Report Builder 5?`

The reports needs DataPipeline properties, will a I lose them if I edit the .RTM files outside their original project?